# Models with many-to-many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, models, polymorphic-associations

I have a test app that I'm trying to setup for practice, the app has Users, who can choose up to 6 Interest Categories when they register.

So, the user can have many interest categories, which will have many "sub" interests ... I am a little confused as to how I can set this up, so that when the user registers, they can choose the 6 interest categories by way of checkboxes on the user registration form.

Should I be using polymorphic associations, or should I create an interest and `interest_category` model with the user model and the `interest_category` model using something like:

```
has_many :interest_categories, :through => :interests ?
```

Also, how can I get the form to save these `interest_categories`? I've tried `f.fields_for :interest_categories`, but they aren't saving.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use has_many `:categories, :through => :categorizables`. You could then add a string field called `:category_type` to the Categorizable model and input "interest" for this case and another string for other cases.

In this way you would have a has many through relationship that's agnostic to the relationship type.

You can then query by `User.categorizables.where(:category_type => "interest")` or setup a scope.

You also might want to consider watching this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes

It's a little outdated, but most likely helpful in setting up your form. There's many ways to approach this, but that's how I'd do it.

Comment: Thanks Stone, I'll watch that railscast.

Comment: Anytime, let me know how it goes.